# I have an SVG image and want to convert it into PNG Tiles to use in leaflet

Tags: svg, leaflet

I am creating a timeline and want to use Leaflet to let users zoom into it. I created an SVG image containing everything. Now I want to convert it into tiles that I can use for Leaflet.

I tried to convert it into a PNG and then crop it, but the file is too large (~120000x70000), and the quality is still so bad that you can't really read the small text.
I also tried using [batik rasterizer](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html) but i coouldnt get it to tile my image.
The only success I had so far was in using MapTiler Engine, but that option is too expensive, and the free version doesn't allow me to set an appropriate zoom.

I have coding knowledge, so either code or software would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what does the SVG look like (you can just add the SVG start tag to your question) and what is the expected result (like 4x10 tiles with the size of...).